# React Native TouchableOpacity not working after adding zIndex

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have a custom component in react-native in which the TouchableOpacity is enclosed within view and the view has zIndex:10, and the TouchableOpacity view has a style with position absolute. In iOS the TouchableOpacity is working fine but in android its not working. Please refer the following code:

```
export function AaMobileSwap({onPress = () => {}}) {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        zIndex: 10,
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        activeOpacity={0.6}
        onPress={onPress}
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          marginLeft: -15.5,
        }}>
        <Icon
          name={"arrow_bidirection_arrow"}
          size={32}
          color={"808080"}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: have you try with ```pointerEvents``` prop of ```View``` .. it has 4 possible values which you can give try .. if it doesn't work then try to give zIndex to TouchableOpacity

Comment: @jayeshgurudayalani nope it didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this attribute to your outer View

```
<View pointerEvents='none'>
```